# jquery hide if html specifically = £

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have some code like this

```
if ($('.lblpricefrom > strong').html() == '£'){
```

$('.lblpricefrom').parents("div.resultsitem").hide();}

But it seems to be hiding items with the class `lblpricefrom` even if the html within = `£456`

I need it to only hide the items with the class `lblpricefrom` if the html within specifically = just `£` and thats it

Thanks

Jamie

UPDATE

this works

```
$('.lblpricefrom > strong').each(
function(){
    if($(this).html() == '£'){
        $(this).parents("div.resultsitem").hide();
    }
});
```

Thanks to Thomas Clayson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... you could do this:

```
$('.lblpricefrom > strong').each(
    function(){
        if($(this).html() == '₤'){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks I edited a bit but your idea works updated my entry above with what worked will mark yours as answer when it lets me lol

Comment: Haha :) I forgot the parents() bit, sorry. Glad I could help. :)